# How to solve '[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named orb_template.py below /opt/ros/fuerte/share/object_recognition_core'?

Tags: ros, object-recognition

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I try to run [object_recognition](http://ecto.willowgarage.com/recognition/ros_quickguide.html) on fuerte.

When I run:

```
  sam@sam:~/code/ros/pcl/pcl_3d_recognition$ rosrun object_recognition_core orb_template.py -o my_textured_plane
  [rosrun] Couldn't find executable named orb_template.py below /opt/ros/fuerte/share/object_recognition_core
  sam@sam:~/code/ros/pcl/pcl_3d_recognition$
```

How to solve it?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44379/how-to-solve-%27%5Brosrun%5D-couldn%27t-find-executable-named-orb_template.py-below-/opt/ros/fuerte/share/object_recognition_core%27-?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-09-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On my installation (checked-out following the instructions for fuerte here: http://ecto.willowgarage.com/recognition/), the orb_template.py resides in object_recognition_capture/apps. D.

---

Originally posted by [dejanpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/92/dejanpan/) with karma: 1420 on 2012-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-09-25**:
Why object_recognition_capture is not a package? That caused me couldn't use rosrun to run orb_template.py.